# JNA Memory Leak - How to fix?

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, java-native-interface, jna

```
        public static User32 USER32_INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

        user32 = USER32_INSTANCE;

        user32.EnumWindows((hWnd, arg) -> {
          int size = 1024 * 8;
          char[] buffer = new char[size];
          USER32_INSTANCE.GetWindowTextW(hWnd, buffer, size);

          char[] buffer2 = new char[size];
          PointerByReference pointer = new PointerByReference();
          User32DLL.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, pointer);
          Pointer process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pointer.getValue());
          Psapi.GetModuleBaseNameW(process, null, buffer2, size);

          String result = Native.toString(buffer).trim();
          String proc = Native.toString(buffer2).trim();

          // ... (non-JNA stuff)
        }
```

I haven't touched C/C++ since college and I honestly have no clue how to actually free the memory here :(

I know that there's a memory leak - I did some profiling with YourKit and traced a memory leak to this block of code (specifically, it seems to be leaking in the GetWindowTextW call and the Native.toString() calls). Could someone just give me an example of how to properly free up whatever memory blocks are being used?

I see that `Pointer` has a `clear()` method, should I use that? But I don't know how to get the size (`clear` takes a length argument). I also see that there's a `Memory` type that subclasses `Pointer`, but according to `instanceof`, none of the Pointers I have right now are actually instances of that.

Comment: are you storing `result` somewhere (preventing it from being freed)?

Comment: I am but I'm fairly certain that has nothing to do with the leak since it's just standard procedure stuff and I'm removing the Strings properly when they're used

Comment: It would be helpful if you created a minimal complete and verifiable example.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After opening a handle to a process with [`OpenProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx), you need to close the process handle with [`CloseHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx). Remember that OpenProcess returns a `Handle`, not a `Pointer`.

```
Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(process);
```

Note also that JNA provides a pretty in-depth mapping of the Windows API out of the box in the net.java.dev.jna-platform package (I think?)

Comment: Thanks! I actually figured this a while back but this confirms my approach was correct (just switching to jna.platform lol) :) I didn't realize there were built-in mappings at first (since you have to include it as a separate jar for Maven). I was looking through the examples in the JNA repo when I found out those existed :P Cut down my code a lot and fixed all the leaks as well!

Comment: Glad you found that other recent question on this. 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Had a slight déjà vu and remembered that I had answered a very similar question before ;)